# Add custom group_id to customers on upload

Tags: magento2, customer, csv

I'm trying to add 5000 customers using the csv uploader. I used the API to add all 5000 customer codes, but when I try to use the csv uploader, it says:

```
 Value for group_id attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin
```

I've reindexed and cleared the cache, so why doesn't it recognize the names as valid? Do I have to download all of the data, and write a script to replace the company names with their id's?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its showing error like customer group_id value is not correct please use below possible values

```
0 for not logged in customer  group 
1 for General customer group 
2 for Wholesale customer group 
3 for Retailer customer group
```

so you can use 1 for group id value if you want to import customer as normal

Comment: The way this company works, each individual customer has it's own group ID, because each customer has custom pricing, so I can't use the regular groups

Comment: ok then you can use newly created customer group ids like if you created new customer group and use that customer group id like 5,6,7 etc

Comment: I tried that, but it keeps erroring out. I'll try reindexing, and run it again

Comment: make sure you already created these new customer groups in admin then only you can use that customer group ids in csv to assign customer to customer group

Comment: I haven't seen that. I tried changing the first 3 records in the csv to their new group ID's, and got the same errors as before

Comment: A few refreshes, and it's working now

Comment: ok great please accept my answer if its help you